# asset files don't load when opening external source with window.open

Tags: javascript

When I try to open external url with `window.open`, window cant load asset files and images..

If I open `xyz.com/test`, window try to load assets files from `localhost/css/style.css` not the real origin.

How do I make window to load its asset files from real origin;

```
var window = window.open(null,null,'width=200,height=200');
window.document.write(htmlSource);
```

Comment: have you tried localhost/xyz.com/css/style.css

Comment: Details your environment. Do your html page is delivered by a php script ? If yes this script is located in your css folder ?

Comment: Are you using a framework ? Laravel ? Zend ? Cake ?

Comment: @Eric Hi eric, yes I'm using laravel, and I'm fetching an external page that needs user authentication. That force me to load source at backend

Comment: You are mixing multiple issues... window.open (url,windowname) :1) are you using null,null as parameter ? 2) Document.write is a function, not a property, use as document.write(something) not write=something. 3) are you using laravel web route or api route ? show us the portion of code where the problem occurs.. the route part, the controller part, and the vue part.

Comment: @Eric thank you for comment, 1- yes I'm sending null as a parameter, 2 I know, I was trying to ask quickly, didn't noticed, I'm using web route and sending html in a json response like ['source'=>'$source']  Also I realized that, target page that I display relative path for assets